# SHA512 crypt returns *0 when rounds=5000

Tags: python, passwords, glibc, crypt

Since some days following python program returns `*0`:

```py
import crypt
# broken:
>>> crypt.crypt('pw', '$6$rounds=5000$0123456789abcdef')
'*0'
# works:
>>> crypt.crypt("pw", '$6$0123456789abcdef')
'$6$0123456789abcdef$zAYvvEJcrKSqV2KUPTUM1K9eaGv20n9mUjWSDZW0QnwBRk0L...'
>>> crypt.crypt('pw', '$6$rounds=5001$0123456789abcdef')
'$6$rounds=5001$0123456789abcdef$mG98GkftS5iu1VOpowpXm1fgefTbWnRm4rbw...'
>>> crypt.crypt("pw", '$6$rounds=4999$0123456789abcdef')
'$6$rounds=4999$0123456789abcdef$ulXwrQtpwNd/t6NVUJo53AXMpp40IrpCHFyC...'
```

I did the same with a small C program using `crypt_r` and the output was the same. I read in some posts that `*0` and `*1` will be returned when there are errors.

According to the manpage `crypt(3)` specifying the `rounds=xxx` parameter is supported since glibc 2.7 and the default is 5000, when no `rounds` parameter is given (like in the second example). **But why am I not allowed to set `rounds` to 5000?**

I'm using Fedora 28 with glibc 2.27. The results are the same with different Python versions (even Python2 and Python3). Using `crypt` in PHP also works as expected. But the most interesting thing is that running the same command in a Docker container (`fedora:28`) works:

```py
>>> crypt.crypt("pw", '$6$rounds=5000$0123456789abcdef')
'$6$rounds=5000$0123456789abcdef$zAYvvEJcrKSqV2KUPTUM1K9eaGv20n9mUjWS...'
```

Does anybody know the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [libxcrypt sources](https://github.com/besser82/libxcrypt/blob/15d1e3bf3d259ea262f3d34e8c225a3abfabaa09/crypt-sha512.c#L125) contain this:

> ```
> /* Do not allow an explicit setting of zero rounds, nor of the
>    default number of rounds, nor leading zeroes on the rounds.  */
> ```

This was [introduced in a commit “Add more tests based on gaps in line coverage.”](https://github.com/besser82/libxcrypt/commit/15d1e3bf3d259ea262f3d34e8c225a3abfabaa09)  with this comment:

> This change makes us pickier about non-default round parameters to $5$ and $6$ hashes; numbers outside the valid range are now rejected, as are numbers with leading zeroes and an explicit request for the
>   default number of rounds.  This is in keeping with the observation, in
>   the Passlib documentation, that allowing more than one valid crypt
>   output string for any given (rounds, salt, phrase) triple is asking
>   for trouble.

I suggest to open an issue if this causes too many compatibility issues.  Alternatively, you can remove the `rounds=5000` specification, but based on a quick glance, the change looks to me as if it should be reverted.  It's not part of the original `libcrypt` implementation in glibc.

Comment: I didn't know that fedora uses libxcrypt... Thanks for figuring out the problem and for your opinion. I opened an issue: https://github.com/besser82/libxcrypt/issues/16.